# How do I use functionality available in an embedded jar file?

Tags: jar, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use GmailSender in my Xamarin Android app. My main project is referencing the binding library, and the binding library has 2 jars - GmailSender 1.1.jar, and mail.jar.

the GmailSender 1.1.jar file is set as an EmbeddedJar in properties, and mail.jar is set as an EmbeddedReferenceJar in properties.

The following image depicts how my project is set up (higher res image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4NGW.png)

[image]

This is where I got GmailSender 1.1.jar: http://gmailsender.blogspot.ie/

This is where I got mail.jar (renamed from mail-6.0.0.jar) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmail600jar.htm

How can I get my Xamarin Android app to use GmailSender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a note regarding that issue on [Xamarin docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/):

> Note: Due to bug 6695, when referencing the Java Binding project
>   directly from a Xamarin.Android project, none of the namespaces,
>   classes, or other members of the Java Binding project will be visible
>   in the IDE when working on the Xamarin.Android project. This bug will
>   be fixed in a future version of Xamarin.Android.

You won't be able to see the bindings unless you **reference the generated dll** (this is a workaround)

Comment: I've been moved off the project that required this functionality so I can't test at the moment - I'll come back to this question when I get a chance to test it.

Comment: Ok.. so I've created a dummy project with a Binding Library and added a random jar file that I found on the web (this one: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadachartengine050jar.htm). I've referenced the Binding Library's dll rather than the project file, and I'm still not seeing anything from the jar file in my android project. What do I need to do to see/use the functionality available in the jar file?

Comment: So I just tried using the regular project reference and it seems to work just fine (contradicting the Xamarin docs). So here is my dummy project for reference with your GmailSender jar.  Give it a look. NOTE: I use Xamarin studio and not VS which shouldn't be an issue (but it might). The dummy project: https://github.com/furmana/JavaLibTest

Comment: It worked. I'll be damned! It seems was all to do with Visual Studio, because I have the project loaded side by side in VS and Xamarin Studio. It builds in Xamarin Studio and not VS. One note though, there is an errant `};` in your `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the library using the namespace of your binding library.  By default, it is probably using "BindingLibrary1" as the root namespace, so try adding a `using` directive for that namespace.

Comment: Hi, I did create a Binding Library, as can be seen in the screen shot.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly didn't read the question closely enough. See my revised answer.

Comment: That doesn't work at all, it's like my tstGmailSender project doesn't even see the BindingLibrary1 project, even though I am referencing it. However, if I add a normal C# class to the BindingLibrary1 project, the tstGmailSender project can see that ok.

Comment: Then I would assume that there is a problem with your binding.

Comment: it seems to be the case. But I'm doing what is outlined in the Xamarin page and i'd like to figure out what the problem is.